# Can't init AudioRecord/AudioTrack when fm radio is playing

Tags: android, audiorecord

```
_audioRecord = new AudioRecord(
                            AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION,
                            sampleRate,
                            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                            recBufSize);

_audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                            AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,
                            sampleRate,
                            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                            playBufSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

When fm radio app not running, it woks well. Please help, thanks

Comment: Hey did you get the solution for this.... i am also facing same problem.. can you please post your solution if you got any?

Comment: No, can't find solution until now.